# BaseGameUtils - unable to compile the source project

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to have leaderboards in my android app. I was trying to use the library BaseGameUtils. This library is referencing the google play services library. When I clean my workspace I get the message for the library BaseGameUtils that the google-play-services_lib.jar is missing in a specified path. But actually the jar file is there in that path. Because of this When I refer the library BaseGameUtils the actual game APP is having an error marking. Kindly assist me to resolve this

[image]

Comment: go to project properties and check the `Java Build Path` section

Answer (score 0):

More info might help to clarify your question more.
But let me see if my being from struggling with the Play Games Service for the past day helps:

first of all, make sure your Google Play Service is updated through SDK manager. After that, COPY THE ENTIRE FOLDER google-play-services_lib to your project and do all the referencing work accordingly.

After all that, check to see if the file res/values/version.xml from google-play-service_lib has the updated version number 4323000